# How to access to AppData folder?

Tags: firefox, batch-file, cd, appdata

I have to write a command line to access the profile folder whose path is:

`C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Thinstall\Mozilla Maintenance Service\%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`

I used this command:

```
cd /D "%APPDATA%\Thinstall\Mozilla Maintenance Service\%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
```

but it's not working because `%AppData%` is a reserved name but here it is the folder name

Comment: Did you tried cd /D "%APPDATA%\Thinstall\Mozilla Maintenance Service\%%AppData%%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" ?

Comment: thanks for reply i traied that but its not work

Comment: Without windows available, it was just a guess because %% is echoed  %, but I see you got the correct escape using ^%

Comment: yes ^% thats worked  ^%appdata^%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `%appdata%` twice. Type `set app` to see it's value.

So assuming your path is right

```
cd "%APPDATA%\Thinstall\Mozilla Maintenance Service\mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
```

PS: Cd and notepad are the two commands that don't require quotes

Comment: thanks for replay but second %APPDATA% is exact name of folder when u use firefox portable in first time that make profiles folder in this path     C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Thinstall\Mozilla Maintenance Service\%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

Comment: Remove the % signs around the second one. It itreally does have percent signs in it (what was mozilla thinking?) escapt them with the `^` caret.

Comment: now i tried but its not work u can check this first make newfolder then rename to %appdata% now try access to this folder with command CD

Comment: I did. Echo out your path. `C:\Users\User>cd ^%appdata^%` prints `C:\Users\User\%appdata%>`.

Comment: @BambiLongGone : it could be nice to update the answer to give an easier access to the right answer instead of getting it from comments